# How to data show Data Row Column in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Here is my data and query. I want row data show in columns... Can someone help me to modify the query? I am using PostgreSQL queries.

```
select 
    ss.name, ip.product_name, ssr.quantity 
from 
    services_servicerecipe ssr
inner join 
    services_service ss on ssr.service_id = ss.id
inner join 
    inventory_product ip on ssr.product_id = ip.id
order by 
    ss.name
```

Output:

```
Service_name |  Product_name    |  Quantity
-------------+------------------+-----------
Balayage     |      7.3-revlon  |   2
Balayage     |      701-revlon  |   1
```

I want it to look like this

```
Service_name |  Product_name     |   Quantity   |  Product_name    | Quantity
-------------+-------------------+--------------+------------------+----------
Balayage     |      7.3-revlon   |   2          |     701-revlon   |   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pivot option, using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
with cte as (
    select ss.name, ip.product_name, ssr.quantity,
        row_number() over (partition by ss.name order by ip.product_name) rn
    from services_servicerecipe ssr
    inner join services_service ss on ssr.service_id = ss.id
    inner join inventory_product ip on ssr.product_id = ip.id
)

select
    name,
    max(case when rn = 1 then product_name end) as product1,
    max(case when rn = 1 then quantity end) as quantity1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then product_name end) as product2,
    max(case when rn = 2 then quantity end) as quantity2
from cte
group by name;
```